# Count character frequency (histogram) in C++/assembly

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, histogram, inline-assembly

i'm brand new to Assembly Language, and could use some help. I'm supposed to be creating a program that uses inline Assembly (masm) and c++ that takes a string of text (up to 127 characters) and inputs into a buffer, and then counts how many instances of each character in the text there are.

E.g. If your string is "baby"

Then b-2, a-1, y-1

The only thing that needs to be  done in assembly is identifying the character and counting how many instances of a letter/number there are. The instances of each character will then be put into another buffer. All this will be done in a function called CountData(). Everything else can be in c++.

I have so far the function to input a text and store it in a buffer, but i still need to write a function CountData() that (in Assembly) reads the entire string and identifies each character and then keeps track of how many of each there are.  However i'm confused on how to access the string in assembly language.  Can i use a for loop and write the assembly code within it? If so, will the assembly code have access to the function's variables/data?
 I tried looking up examples but can't really find anything relevant. Not looking to have my homework done for me, just want a little push in the right direction. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
class BaseClass
{
private:
     const int characterNumber = 127;
     cont int asciiNumber = 59;
     char InputBuffer[characterNumber];
     char CountBuffer[asciiNumber];
public:

     InputData()
     {
          string sentence;
          cout << "Enter a sentence to have its characters counted: " << endl;
          cin.getline(InputBuffer, characterNumber);
     }

     CountData()
     {

     }


};
```

Comment: write it in C++ first.   in assembly its just an address and a byte, no magic to it.  so no different than C++ you need the base address, then you walk through incrementing the address or using a base+offset approach until you find a zero indicating end of the string.

Comment: what part of this are you confused about?  real assembly is easier btw not inline, but dont know what your desire/requirements are. inline you can probably make a loop outside the inline asm but will find you want the loop to be in asm.

Comment: start by addressing and reading the first character of the "string".  that will get you about a third to half the way there.

Comment: i'll have to try again after i get off work, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this could be considered cheating, but like old_timer said in a comment, write it in c++ but then instruct the compiler to emit assembly.   With msvc the switch is /Fa, and you'll probably want to include /Od to disable optimizations so it's not so arcane.

Once you see how the compiler does it, you'll have a better idea how you can go about it.

Comment: Usually you want to optimize some, e.g. for code-size or some optimization without auto-vectorization.  Debug mode spills every C variable to memory between every statement, making it *harder* to follow by hand for simple functions.  e.g. [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Comment: `/Od` is the same anti-optimized code-gen as debug mode that keeps all variables in memory between statements.  The extra stores/reloads make it harder to follow for very simple code.  `/Os` (optimize for code-size) doesn't unroll or vectorize.  It might use pointer-increment instead of array indexing, sure, but if you have the first clue about asm it's a lot easier to follow.  All the same arguments apply for MSVC as for GCC; `gcc -O0` is very much equivalent to MSVC `/Od`.